# implement separate templates for 1 post type

Tags: permalinks, templates

- I have a custom post type 'courses', with a course description as post_content, and number of attachments
- I also have a custom post type 'course units', linked to the courses with a custom field 'course-id'
- I created a template file for the course dashboard, showing a list of the units, and a couple of links - to the course description, and to an archive of the attachments.

My (pretty generic) question:

- I'm stuck at how to create/implement the seperate 'pages' for the description, and the attachment archive - can't get my head around it.

Some additional info:

- I'm not using 'pretty permalinks' (because of some plugin conflicts), so the URL of the course dashboard is just http://www.example.com/?course=slug-of-the-course
- Ideally the description should be available on something like http://www.example.com/?course=slug-of-the-course&showdesc=1, and the attachments on http://www.example.com/?course=slug-of-the-course&showatt=1 - both URLs should forward to a specific template file in my theme folder.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use template redirect action to check if there is parameter set for description and based on that you can show desired template.

```
<?php 

add_action('template_redirect', 'course_template_redirect', 1);

function course_template_redirect()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if($wp_query->post_type=='courses' and $_REQUEST['showdesc']=='1')
    {
        //include your template from your theme folder. for e.g include('mytheme/coursetemplate.php');

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: that seems like a perfect solution, thanks for pointing me to 'template_redirect', never heard of it. just one issue: for some reason, the original course template file (single-course.php) is appended after the closing `body` tag - I suppose I also have to 'exclude' this template file in some way - any idea how to to this?

Comment: Also - just for future reference - I had to change `$wp_query->post_type` to `get_post_type()` to make it work...

Comment: Already found the fix: just had to add `exit()` after the include, this prevents the original template from being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If the description and attachments require separate URLs then I would create the 'attachments' as a separate post type to the 'courses' which contain the description.

Then from your main custom post type 'courses' I would create reciprocal relationships from each course to its units and attachments using the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.

Comment: Could be a good workaround indeed, thanks for the suggestion. I prefer the solution by Rajeev, however, it's a bit more elegant - no need for extra post types...